# When did saying "I'm offended" or "I find that offensive" become a common phrase in English?

Tags: historical-change, origin-unknown

When did saying *I’m offended* or *I find that offensive* become a common phrase in English?

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparative graph from [Google Books ngram utility](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20find%20that%20offensive%2C%20I%27m%20offended&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20find%20that%20offensive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20offended%3B%2Cc0):[image: ngram of 2 phrases]
Whether this graph confirms your hypothesis regarding the rise of political correctness (per your tag) depends of course on what that hypothesis is, but also and perhaps more interestingly on what your *definition* of political correctness is.

Comment: But *"I'm offended"* has gained popularity recently only because it replaced *"I am offended"*. People didn't use to use contractions much in writing. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+offended&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20offended%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: *(There seems to be some inconsistencies when using URLs directly to Google NGrams that have (encoded) apostrophes.)* Try pasting this into the query box for a better picture: `I find that offensive,I'm offended,I am offended,(I'm offended + I am offended)`